Admin API of BIM360 vs ACC - Remove user from a project
We have older projects on BIM360 and newer project on ACC.
I am using the account admin API to add users :

BIM360 -
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/
ACC -
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projects-project-Id-users-POST/

I can remove users from ACC using this endpoint :

ACC-
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projects-project-Id-users-userId-DELETE/

Is there a way to remove users from BIM360 ?  (it clearly says on each that these endpoints are either ACC or BIM360 , i.e. no compatibility )
P/S Is there another way around this - perhaps use the import endpoint to remove users from projects ?
Thanks , Jonathan Talisman

DELETE API: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projects-project-Id-users-userId-DELETE/ is only limited on ACC projects. It is not compatible and won't work with BIM 360 projects.
Autodesk does not have any API that can remove members from BIM 360 projects currently.
